# Polymorphic Posting in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I would like to run this past SO before implementing this.

I have **Users** and **Groups**, both of which can create **Posts** and both of which can receive **Posts**.

I'm thinking I need 2 polymorphic association on the Posts model like this:

*posted* and *wall* (posted shows a model can create posts, wall shows models can receive posts)

So both User and Group should:

```
has_many :posts, :as => :posted
has_many :posts, :as => :wall
```

and Post should have

```
belongs_to :posted, :polymorphic => true
belongs_to :wall, :polymorphic => true
```

Also, should I be using the "able" convention I seem to see with Rails polymorphism? **Postable** and **Wallable**
It seems more readable to have User.wall for their wall and User.posted for a record of their own posts. ( I might even change *wall* to *recieved*? )

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Poloymorphic**

I think by its nature, you're getting the [Polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) confused:

[image]

It's meant to provide the ability to associate *different* models to a single model; for example if you had the following:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tables, as: :bookable
end

#app/models/admin.rb
Class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :parties, as: :bookable
end

#app/models/restaurant.rb
Class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :bookable, polymorphic: true
end
```

--

**Single Table Inheritance**

You're trying to associate the same model multiple times from a single model. Whilst this is okay, I would surmise that you're really looking for an [STI](http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance):

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :wall_posts, class_name: "User::WallPost"
   has_many :posts, class_name: "User::Post"
end

#app/models/post.rb
Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/user/wall_post.rb
Class User::WallPost < Post
end

#app/models/user/post.rb
Class User::Post < Post
end
```

This will allow you to perform the following:

```
@user = User.find 1
@user.wall_posts.each do |post|
   post.name
end
```

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to understand how this fits my issue? A post has an author and a recipient. therefore it needs an author_id and a recipient_id. However, both author and recipient could be either a User or a Group. I agree that somthing seems wrong with my solution.. but I don't get your solution